# how to store NULL into the node?

Tags: c, linked-list

I came across below interview question on the net.

" Write the code for Getnextnode function in a singly LL with following prototype

```
Node GetNextNode(Node n);
```

and validate it "

The generic case solution is straight forward like something below:

```
Node GetNextNode(Node n)
{
    Node temp = *(n.link);
        return temp;
}
```

I am wondering if `n` is the last node in the list. `n.link` will point to `NULL`, in that case how to return it.

Also if `head` is pointer to first node in the list and if list is empty how to pass it to `GetNextNode` function.

Any direction please. Thanks.

Comment: Why Not make it return a pointer and take a pointer?

Comment: With this method signature it cannot return null, but a Node sentinel value could be used. Do not forget that dereferencing a null_ptr is undefined behavior so that needs to be checked as well.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III I wish that would be the case, but question has explicit prototype mentioned.

Comment: @Joe -I am not quite sure on sentinel value usage. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @CppLearner You have shown us a function prototype. Does the problem also specify what `Node` is? If not, you can treat it as if there is a `typedef struct Node *Node` somewhere.

Comment: @ mteckert : sorry my bad , Node is a generic structure like struct Node {int data; Node * link;};

Comment: A [sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) value is just dummy data guaranteed to not be a legal value. You would essentially have some `Node` whose address or values could be used to mark the end of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way to store the end of the list, have `link` point to the node itself. In such a way your link is always valid and you can simply test for the end by comparing the two for equality.